# How to run a Laravel application that was not created by me on my personal server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to alter some of the front-end features of a Laravel application that was not created by me. The application was created using Laravel and am not sure how  to get it up and running so I can alter the front-end code. I was given a copy of the source files. I then put that source files in to my `xampp/htdocs` folder. I started Xampp, opened the folder in Gitbash and entered PHP artisan serve. The application does not appear to be running.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Please take into consideration that I did not create this application, for your information, I do know how to create and run a Laravel app locally, but am wondering if the process is different if it was not created by me personally?

Thank you all for helping me out, I appreciate you personally and this community.

Here is the error I am receiving in Gitbash:

> PHP Warning: 
>   require(C:\xampp\htdocs\appoets\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>        failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\appoets\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>        Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\appoets\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\appoets\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\xampp\htdocs\appoets\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\appoets\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>        Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\appoets\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\appoets\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Please solved this for me. If you run into the same error. Have the correct file path open in Gitbash and then run "composer install"

After that was fixed another problem popped up. I went to load Laravel in my browser and it gave a general error message no error number or anything. To fix this go to your `env.example` file and rename it. `.env` then go to the terminal or your command line and run `php artisan key:generate`. After this hit save all and go refresh. All should be fixed!

Comment: It shouldn't be any different whether someone else wrote the code or you. Just so we can have more information: what makes you think the application isn't running? Are you getting errors when running `php artisan serve`? Or just getting a "cannot connect to host" error in your browser?

Comment: @HPierce Exactly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors your getting are because you haven't installed your composer dependencies. Install them with composer before running the application:

`composer install`

Here's the old answer before that callstack was provided. I think it's still interesting background information for you, but not immediately relevant.

> It looks like you're running two web servers so I suspect you're just
>   confused about where the application is running.
>
> XAMPP ships with Apache. I'd expect that running it will spin up its
>   web server on port 80, the default port that web browsers use.
>   Therefore, if you're trying to get to the application at
>   http://localhost, you're hitting this webserver, which might have a
>   different (and not set up) application on it.
>
> Running `php artisan serve` will start *a second* web server utilizing
>   PHP's built in web server. According to [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/quick), the
>   default port that this command will use is 8000:
>
> > By default the HTTP-server will listen to port 8000. However if that
> >     port is already in use or you wish to serve multiple applications this
> >     way, you might want to specify what port to use. Just add the --port
> >     argument:
>
> Therefore, you can access the application without XAMPP though this
>   url: http://localhost:8000
>
> Try both URLs.
>
> Note that `php artisan serve` *doesn't* start up a MySQL server. You
>   will still need XAMPP to start the MySQL server if you're using a
>   database.

Comment: so once I get the dependencies, I just need to copy the existing files into the newly created project? Right now I am making a new laravel app and then I am going to import the files he gave me. will this work? Because the version I created has the dependencies installed.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're planning on generating a new Laravel app and coping an existing Laravel project files into it? I would definitely advise against it. The files you were given may have been built on a different Laravel version. `composer install` inside the correct project should give you whatever the correct Laravel version that are needed  (among other things) - no manual copying required.

Comment: Dude, I love you....it worked! May I ask how you knew to do that or where you learned that from? Did you run into the same problem sometime back?

Comment: @Russell, Glad to hear it :-) I've learned it over a few years of doing software engineering with PHP and building apps with composer. BUT I have definitely gone to a meetup where a few front-end devs were running into _this exact problem_. You're certainly not alone. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Checklist for your issue

```
 1. composer update --no-scripts  or composer install
 2. php artisan key:generate 
 3. rename example.env to .env
 4. Change database credentials, set debug mode! Change app url
 4. php artisan migrate(make sure u have the database running in the server)
 5. php artisan config:clear
 6. you are good to go!
```

Comment: I'd be nervous about `composer update`... It's going to re-resolve dependencies and update the lock file. I wouldn't want a front-end dev swooping in and changing versions on my dependencies without being able to test myself from a backend perspective. Thought it would _probably_ not be a problem.